# How to calculate the probability of something that relies on multiple booleans when some of them are repeated.

Tags: probability, boolean-algebra

Ok, sorry for the ambiguous / weird title but I don't know what to call to my problem.

My question is, imagine I have three booleans A, B and C that will randomly be true or false. Now imagine I have different variables that will calculate their value based on these three variables. For example:

object1 = `A` (so object1 will be true if A is true, 50% chance)

object2 = `!A` (so object2 will be true if A is false, 50% chance)

object3 = `A & B` (25% chance)

now, if I complicate this and say object4 is `A & A`, or `A & !A`, or `B & (A & (!C & !B))`, how can I properly calculate these probabilities? It is obvious to me that I have to discard repeated values (so A & A = A) and address contradictions (A & !A will always be false), but I don't know how to express this mathematically.

Comment: Probably worth looking at Karnaugh maps, which is a process of simplifying boolean expressions.

Comment: It's important to know whether the three boolean variables are uniformly distributed (equally likely to be true or false) and independent. That's usually what we have in mind when defining three random boolean variables, but if you're concerned about expressing things mathematically, these are important properties. If the variables are uniform and independent then the $25\%$ chance for $A \& B$ is justified.

Comment: Yes, each variable has is a 50/50 and not related to any other variable.